# Setting up Message Tracing for WSO2 ESB 4.8.1with BAM 2.4.0 Not Working

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb4.8.1 and wso2bam is 2.4.0.
I wish to trace the messages of wso2esb4.8.1. I am trying to install **Message tracing for the ESB** Future for that in my wso2esb4.8.1. It is however not working.
I have tested with Echo service String Operation.
I followed this link. [It has a good description but isn't working in the end](https://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM241/Setting+up+Message+Tracing+for+WSO2+ESB).

In wso2esb, the error error log is:

```
[2014-05-22 11:22:10,762]  INFO - HandlerUtils Massage Info: Transaction id=5684
82352184655268848  Message direction=IN  Server name=10.50.56.69:9765  Timestamp
=1400737930683  Service name=echo  Operation Name=echoString
[2014-05-22 11:22:10,765]  INFO - HandlerUtils Massage Info: Transaction id=5684
82352184655268848  Message direction=OUT  Server name=10.50.56.69:9765  Timestam
p=1400737930765  Service name=echo  Operation Name=echoString
[2014-05-22 11:22:11,791] ERROR - AsyncDataPublisher Error while connection to e
vent receiver
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.exception.AgentException: Cannot borrow
client for TCP,localhost:9763,TCP,localhost:9863
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authentica
tor.AgentAuthenticator.connect(AgentAuthenticator.java:58)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.DataPublisher.start(DataPubli
sher.java:273)

        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.DataPublisher.<init>(DataPubl
```

And WSO2BAM is also throwing errors tcp localhost is not working
I have given the **RecieverURL** as `tcp://localhost:9763` in WSO2ESB  **Message Tracing Configuration**
Now the errors in WSO2BAM are like this:

```
[2014-05-22 10:40:58,957]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.dashboard.common.oauth.GSOAuthM
odule} -  Using random key for OAuth client-side state encryption
[2014-05-22 10:40:59,518]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComp
onent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://10.50.56.69:9443/carbon/
[2014-05-22 10:40:59,519]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComp
onent} -  Gadget Server Default Context : http://10.50.56.69:9763/portal
[2014-05-22 10:43:41,276]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthen
ticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2014-05-22 10:43:41,
275+0530]
[2014-05-22 10:45:26,945] ERROR {me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.CassandraHost}
 -  Unable to resolve host tcp://localhost
[2014-05-22 10:45:26,949] ERROR {me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnection
Manager} -  Could not start connection pool for host tcp://localhost(tcp://local
host):9160
[2014-05-22 10:46:15,491] ERROR {me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnection
Manager} -  Could not start connection pool for host localhost(127.0.0.1):9161
[2014-05-22 11:22:58,840]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthen
ticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2014-05-22 11:22:58,
839+0530]
[2014-05-22 11:23:14,098] ERROR {me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnection
Manager} -  Could not start connection pool for host localhost(127.0.0.1):9161
[2014-05-22 11:24:04,274]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthen
ticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2014-05-22 11:24:04,
273+0530]
```

So what is the error? I followed as it is as per docs, but am not getting the desired result.

Comment: If i give this url tcp://localhost:7613 and test its is not connecting then i have tried with this tcp://localhost:9763 testing is ok but giving above errors

Comment: Even i have tried with wso2esb4.8.0 found same error log in this also

Comment: even i have treid with wso2esb4.8.0 sameerrors getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the port offset values of ESB and BAM? Please use the thrift address and port that display in BAM server startup logs. The problem here is ESB can't sent events to BAM. Based on your first log output message tracing works(check very first INFO logs)

Comment: ESb offset 2 Bam offset 0 ..I think issue is with tcp://localhost:****   which port number i should give

Comment: Great its working ..trying for data agent now again getting errors for that